# How to fix random mouse jumping?

Tags: mouse, debug

For some reason, a couple days ago my Ubuntu 16.04 partition started acting up. When I am typing or moving the mouse or clicking the mouse, every few seconds the mouse will randomly jump and click other places on the screen (I think only the left side of the screen). Sometimes it happens when I am not touching the computer but not nearly as much. It does not happen at all on my windows partition. It still happens if I turn off the mouse pad and plug in a mouse. It makes my Linux partition basically unusable.

Comment: When you boot from a LiveUSB and run from that, does it still occur?

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: @K7AAY it still does the same thing

Comment: Then try another LiveUSB from another distro.

Comment: I have a lot of things saved to this already. That doesn't help

Comment: It's not a solution, just a troubleshooting step to see if the issue is related to GNOME.

Comment: Gotcha. I will try that and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: _"It makes my Linux partition basically unusable."_ — not true! you could be using the Linux console! :-)